# Find the longest continuum in the array that the sum of the values in the continuum equal to zero modulo 3

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote a code that finds the longest continuum in the array that the sum of the values in the continuum equal to zero modulo 3, e.g for the array `a[]={2,-3,5,7,-20,7}`

We have 2-3+5+7-20=-9 so the output is 5, **My problem is** the complexity, now it's `O(n^3)` a bird whispered me that it can be done in `O(n)`

```
public class mmn {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a[]={2,-3,5,7,-20,7};
    int r=what(a);
    System.out.println(r);
}
private static int f(int[]a,int low, int high)
{
int res=0;
for (int i=low;i<=high;i++)
    res+=a[i];
return res;
}
    public static int what(int[]a)
    {
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=i;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            int c=f(a,i,j);
            if (c%3==0)
            {
                if(j-i+1>temp)
                    temp=j-i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
    }

}
```

**Attempt to rewrite in O(n):**

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
// you should use only one Scanner object
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a[]={3,1,3,1,3,1};
int n=a.length;
int S[]=new int[n];
int i[]=new int[n];
int best;
int sum;

for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    S[j]=a[j]%3;
    i[j]=j;// initialize
    //System.out.println(S[j]);
    //System.out.println(i[j]);     
}
best=1;
for (int k=1; k<n; k++) {
    if((S[k-1]+S[k])%3==0) {//checking if we want a longer continuum
        S[k]=S[k-1]+a[k];
        i[k]=i[k-1];
    }    
    if(S[k]<S[best])//check if i should update the better
        best=k-1;
    }
    System.out.println(best);
}
}
```

Comment: Get the bird to tell you its method.

Comment: `-3+5+7-20+7` is `-4`, not `-3`

Comment: Birds cannot be trusted. Especially seagulls

Comment: Doing it in O(n*n) is easy, but because while extending a subarray, the net sum modulo 3 do not always goes into a particular direction. I think that bird is actually an EAGLE, as how that observed it in O(n) time?

Comment: You should specify what's wrong with your attempt, otherwise it isn't clear why did you post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an illustration of an `O(n)` algorithm in Python, making one pass over the array. The idea is that `dp[i][r]` represents the longest sequence, `s`, ending at index `i` where `(sum s) % 3 = r`. Cleary we look for the highest `dp[i][0]`. We can only augment the sequence for a particular cell if the previous step recorded any length at all for the appropriate modulo result. Since we access only three cells (a constant) on each iteration through the array, the algorithm has `O(n)` time and space complexity. (Space can be easily adapted to `O(1)` since we only need the previous three cells at each iteration.)

```py
a = [2,-3,5,7,-20,7]

best = 0
bestIndex = -1

dp = [[0,0,0] for i in range(len(a) + 1)]

for i in range(1,len(a) + 1):
  r = a[i-1] % 3

  for j in range(3):
    canSumToJ = dp[i-1][(3 + j - r) % 3] > 0

    dp[i][j] = max(1 if r == j else 0
                  ,1 + dp[i-1][(3 + j - r) % 3] if canSumToJ else 0)

  bestIndex = i - 1 if dp[i][0] > best else bestIndex
  best = max(best,dp[i][0])

print(best,(bestIndex - best + 1, bestIndex)) # (5, (0, 4))

# dp
# => [[0, 0, 0]
#    ,[0, 0, 1]
#    ,[1, 0, 2]
#    ,[0, 3, 2]
#    ,[3, 1, 4]
#    ,[5, 4, 2]
#    ,[3, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: היי גלעד מהו די פי? הפלט אמור להיות אורך הרצף הארוך ביותר שסכומו מתחלק בשלוש ללא שארית

Comment: Can someone translate it to Java? please!!

Comment: @Nehorai
הפלט נכתב בשורה האחרונה עם ה'פרינט'. הוספתי את די פי להראות איך החישוב נראה.

Comment: @Error404 I am not versed in Java but I could write it in JavaScript if you like. It's very simple - the `for` is just a for loop, where `range` is like `i=0; i<variable; i++`. The declaration for `dp` is just a two-dimensional array `(array_length + 1)x3`, with values set to zero. The rest would be pretty much the same in Java.

Answer (score 2):

After computing the prefix sum s[] using dynamic programming, then you can iterate over s and store in a new array of pair s[i]%3 in index i such that first indices is the min indices and the second one is the max indeces, so that new array have length 3, then iterate the new array and store the count of 0,1,2, finally iterate that array again, and find max between
(cnt[ 3 - moduloArray[i] ].first - i,cnt[ 3 - moduloArray[i] ].second - i).

Answer (score -1):

For the fun of it:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = IntStream.range(0, arrayLenght).mapToObj(x -> x)
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i, arrayLenght)
                    .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.stream(array).skip(i).limit(arrayLenght - j).mapToObj(t -> t)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

int result = list.stream().filter(l -> l.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(u -> u)) % 3 == 0)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(List::size))
            .map(List::size)
            .orElse(-1);
```

It probably can be improved even further to use a bit less operations.

But at least it will work for inputs like:

> [1,3,3,3,1]